# Kubernetes Pod Security Policies

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-psp

> Pod security policy control is implemented as an optional (but
>   recommended) admission controller. PodSecurityPolicies are enforced by
>   enabling the admission controller, but doing so without authorizing
>   any policies will prevent any pods from being created in the cluster.
>
> Since the pod security policy API (policy/v1beta1/podsecuritypolicy)
>   is enabled independently of the admission controller, for existing
>   clusters it is recommended that policies are added and authorized
>   before enabling the admission controller.

**Question:**

I need to create a cluster , and then later define a pod security policy to restrict an account/credential to run pods in restricted manner.

Does this will apply to that particular account or all the pods in the cluster? I prefer to keep the default admin account unrestricted while allow only a fix uid/gid for that particular user account to run pods.

I just doubt that if I restrict the pods to runAs only a fix uid/gid , it may break things in the cluster?

How to apply a pod security policy to all the users/service accounts in all the namespaces ( existing and new ) , except cluster admin

Comment: Looks like PSP work by denying all pods, but then if you give permission to a user or service account to `use` a given policy then it can create pods if those pods match the policies its permitted to use. Perhaps you could create a PSP that requires a certain uid/gid and configure authz (eg RBAC) to allow all principals to use that PSP, and then create an additional PSP that allows any uid/gid to be used and only authorize the admin user and/or the default service account in the system namespace to use that PSP?

Answer (score 1):

Following this post:

https://medium.com/coryodaniel/kubernetes-assigning-pod-security-policies-with-rbac-2ad2e847c754

Turns out that I can create two PSPs:

1. Privileged
2. Restricted

Admin has access to both of them by default , but they are assigned alphabetically so I can name them like:

01-Privileged

and

100-Restricted

So for Admin , the effective one will be the first one.

For normal users , I will just assign the restricted one through clusterRole and Rolebinding for all authenticated users.

But it turns out that applying PSP to user accounts works for creating simple pods , but if they try to create replicasets as part of deployments , it won't work , and we need to assign the policy to pod service accounts as well.